# Class object as a context parameter in jsp

Tags: jsp, object, servlets, parameters

This is related to a jsp web application.. 
Can I store object of some class as a context parameter and then write a listener for the context to initialize the object. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you know how to convert from `String` to that instance. Init parameter values can only be strings, simply because they're stored in a textbased file (XML). Pass it for example to the constructor of your object so that it can initialize its state based on it. E.g. by splitting the value on a comma and then setting several fields with it. You've all the freedom to write code accordingly.

```
String value = servletContext.getInitParameter("name");
YourObject yourObject = new YourObject(value);
// ...
```